Unable to get sellable Item in Sitecore commerce
I'm trying to check whether Sellable item exists or not and using below code, but it is always returning null whether Sellable item is present or not in database.
public class GetCommerceEntity : CommerceCommand
{
    private readonly CommerceCommander _commander;
    public GetCommerceEntity(CommerceCommander commander, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        : base(serviceProvider)
    {
        _commander = commander;
    }

    public virtual async Task<bool> Process(CommerceContext commerceContext, ImportJSONDto importJSONDto)
    {
        using (CommandActivity.Start(commerceContext, this))
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await _commander.Command<GetSellableItemCommand>().Process(commerceContext, "Entity-SellableItem-" + importJSONDto.EntityId.ToString().Trim(), true);
                if (result != null) { return true; }
                else { return false; }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(ex.StackTrace);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}



Did you debug and check the value of importJSONDto.EntityId ? Usually EntityId already contains the prefix you are appending here.

Yes, I've checked it finally passing this- Entity-SellableItem-2416129. Also, same code checked with colleague system, same result i.e. null. Added screen shot for your reference. Thanks

Can you try getting using this command
public class GetCommerceEntity : CommerceCommand
{
    private readonly GetSellableItemCommand _getSellableItemCommand;
    public GetCommerceEntity(GetSellableItemCommand getSellableItemCommand, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        : base(serviceProvider)
    {
        _getSellableItemCommand = getSellableItemCommand;
    }

    public virtual async Task<bool> Process(CommerceContext commerceContext, ImportJSONDto importJSONDto)
    {
         using (var activity = CommandActivity.Start(commerceContext, this))
         {
            try
            {
                var identifier = $"Entity-SellableItem-{importJSONDto.EntityId.ToString().Trim()}"; // Verify the prefix
                var result = await _getSellableItemCommand.Process(commerceContext, identifier ).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
                if (result != null) { return true; }
                else { return false; }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                 Log.Error(ex.StackTrace);
                 return false;
            }
        }
    }
}

Hope this helps !

We faced this issue in one of our project and found that whenever we were adding or updating any item, a restart or IIS reset was required to reflect the sellable items. Please do that and try again that may help.
